# HTTP post JSON java

Tags: java, http, post, json

I'm trying to post some json data using a http post method within my android application however i cannot seem to get it to work, the string is building fine and it works if i test using google chrome addon advanced rest client. I'm not the strongest with JSON hence why it is a string and not a JSON object. The Post request does not execute. Thanks in advance

```
    String json = "{\"data\": [";
for (String tweet : tweetContent)
{
    json = json + "{\"text\": \"" + tweet + "\", \"query\": \"" + SearchTerm + "\", \"topic\": \"movies\"},";
}
json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 1);
json = json + "]}";

Log.i("matt", json);





// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson?appid=matt-43@hotmail.com");

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json, HTTP.UTF_8);


httppost.setEntity(entity);

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, responseBody);
    sentiments.add(responseBody.toString());
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Set the content type while you're at it.

Comment: it does not execute the post request

Answer (score 0):

what is the response code that you are getting back after posting from the Http client.

It should be 200 for a successful Http post. Other wise there is some issue.

You are posting the JSON data to the URL. which application is reading this data from the URL. Is there some servlet on the other application that is reading JSON data fromrequest. check that and see.

Also check the request headers for the Http Post request. if you are setting all the request headers properly.

Comment: I'm not recieving any response at all, its almost as if the post request is not being fired at all

Comment: Do you mean the Response object is null? If not , what status does it have?

Comment: Yes the response is null, it's as if the code is never fired